# Understanding __PAIR__ macro from IDA PRO Pseudo Decompiler to look better

Tags: ida, decompilation, decompiler

When I decompile using IDA PRO I get code which could look like both of these

Understanding the `__PAIR__` macro.

Macro itself.

```
// The following definition is not quite correct because it always returns
// uint64. The above C++ functions are good, though.
#define __PAIR__(high, low) (((unsigned long)(high)<<sizeof(high)*8) | low)
```

```
if ( (__PAIR__(a4, a3) & 0x8000000000000000ui64) == 0i64 ) {
  //condition code.
}
```

I also have code that looks like this

```
  if ( (__PAIR__(v17, v12) & 0x8000000000000000ui64) != 0i64 ) {
    //condition code.
  }
```

I actually found some guy who helped me repair this bad looking code and as far I could tell by the pattern they could simply be replaced like so.

```
   if( (__PAIR__(a4, a3) & 0x8000000000000000ui64) == 0i64 )
```

becomes

```
   if(a4 >= 0 && a3 >= 0)
```

Now I found a very similar pattern that looks like above but instead of `== 0i64` it has `!= 0i64`

So I figured if my pattern is correct then the following code below

```
  if ( (__PAIR__(v17, v12) & 0x8000000000000000ui64) != 0i64 ) {
```

should look like this

```
  if( v17 < 0 || v12 < 0 ) {
```

Then again that's just a guess I wonder if that's correct.

I can't post the assembly for the `!= 0i64` example as I couldn't find it the assembly code is very big.. but the one with `== 0i64` looks like this

```
.text:004049F0                 mov     edx, [esp+a3]
.text:004049F4                 test    edx, edx
.text:004049F6                 jl      short locret_404A3E
.text:004049F8                 mov     eax, [esp+a4]
.text:004049FC                 test    eax, eax
.text:004049FE                 jl      short locret_404A3E
```

Answer (score 4):

> ```
>  if( (__PAIR__(a4, a3) & 0x8000000000000000ui64) == 0i64 )
> ```
>
> becomes
>
> ```
>  if(a4 >= 0 && a3 >= 0)
> ```

No, that's not correct. The correct simplification is:

```
if ((int)a4 >= 0)
```

> ```
>  if ( (__PAIR__(v17, v12) & 0x8000000000000000ui64) != 0i64 ) {
> ```
>
> should look like this
>
> ```
>  if( v17 < 0 || v12 < 0 ) {
> ```

Nope, it should look like this:

```
if ((int)v17 < 0) {
```

You may want to read up on how the [most significant bit (MSB)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_significant_bit) is used as the [sign bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_bit) in [two's complement notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Comment: But it seems to be a PAIR of 2 variables why only one is used there? I understand the variables could be created out of thin-air due to the way assembly works. But I do believe this should still check both at once am I wrong? also since it checks for a 64 bit mask i'm guessing thats 32 bit per variable? this is made for x86 exe not 64bit exe.

Comment: It appears in the disassembly as two variables because the original code used a 64-bit variable, which gets broken up into two 32-bit variables in the disassembly. Since only the MSB of the 64-bit value is checked (since the code is checking the value's sign), the lower DWORD portion of the 64-bit value is irrelevant, which is why my simplified code above ignores a3 and v12.

Comment: So as far as I understand IDA PRO did a bad analyze on the assembly to think it's 64bit when it's really 2 variables DWORDS. Why does the assembly above I posted have a3 and a4 I think the asm is interpreted the same in ollydebugger as well that assembly is for the `== 0i64`

Comment: "IDA PRO did a bad analyze on the assembly to think it's 64bit when it's really 2 variables DWORDS" -- no, it really is a 64 bit value; IDA didn't make a mistake here as far as I can see.