# What does _PAIR_ macro do with standard handles?

Tags: disassembly

I've seen this [question](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/8317/23069) which says `__PAIR__` macro does some conditional computation. But I can not relate that with standard I/O handles. Here is the pseudocode in IDA:

```
if ( (char *)hConout - 1 <= (char *)0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFDi64 ) {
ConfigureStdHandles((PHANDLE)handle);
v175 = __PAIR__(1, (unsigned int)handle[0]);
v176 = __PAIR__(2, (unsigned int)handle[1]);
v177 = __PAIR__(2, (unsigned int)handle[2]);
```

Here is the corresponding Assembly:

```
loc_1400088CA:                          ; CODE XREF: wmain+FBF↑j
mov     [rsp+418h+handle+18h], rsi
lea     rax, [rsi-1]
cmp     rax, 0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFDh
setbe   al
mov     rcx, [rsp+418h]
test    al, al
jz      loc_140008BAD
lea     rcx, [rsp+418h+handle] ; hIn
call    _ConfigureStdHandles
mov     esi, 1
mov     dword ptr [rsp+418h+var_268+4], esi
mov     eax, dword ptr [rsp+418h+handle]
mov     dword ptr [rsp+418h+var_268], eax
mov     dword ptr [rsp+418h+var_260+4], 2
mov     eax, dword ptr [rsp+418h+handle+8]
mov     dword ptr [rsp+418h+var_260], eax
mov     dword ptr [rsp+418h+var_258+4], 2
mov     eax, dword ptr [rsp+418h+handle+10h]
mov     dword ptr [rsp+418h+var_258], eax
cmp     [rsp+418h+var_230], r15b
jz      short loc_140008958
mov     [rsp+418h+var_268], r15
loc_140008958:
```

The handles are for standard input, output and error respectively. Can you explain what does the `__PAIR__` macro do with those handles?

Comment: show the corresponding asm

Comment: it appears like highpart(qword( x) = var; lowpart(qword(x) - another var;

Comment: nothing   take a look at _LARGE_INTEGER structure  and see  the low part and high part and also as a qword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__PAIR__` represents a 64-bit value constructed from two 32-bit values. Because you have 64-bit variables (`var_260` etc) being initialized by halves, decompiler detected a 64-bit move pattern and represented the right-hand side it as `__PAIR__` helper. If you think it's wrong, you can fix it by:

1. fixing the stack variable to be two 32-bit ones instead of one 64-bit. You can do it by opening the stack frame view (e.g double-click on the stkvar)  and editing the  frame structure (e.g with D key). After refreshing (F5), the decompiler should show simple 32-bit assignments without `__PAIR__`.
2. splitting the 64-bit assignment into separate 32-bit ones. For that, use ["Split Assignment"](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/manual/cmd_split.shtml) in the context menu.

---

***EDIT*** I suspect that those stack variables are not 64-bit integers but actually small structs of two members, e.g.

```
struct handle_desc {
  int handle;
  int index;
}
```

maybe look at how they’re used later in the code.

Comment: After splitting `v175 = __PAIR__(1, (unsigned int)handle[0]);` becomes `HIDWORD(v175) = 1; LODWORD(v175) = handle[0];`.

Comment: yes, because the stkvar is still a 64-bit integer but high and low parts of it are being accessed separately.

Comment: How did you guess handle will be first member then index?

Comment: because handles are assigned to the low part of the variable. but you could try both and see which one works better.